# Find all cycles that return to starting node in a Directed Graph up to a certain length

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'd like to find (and track the paths) for all cycles in a Directed Graph up to length N that begin and return to a given 'start' node I specify.

I've tried bellman ford as it turns out I'm also interested in negative weight cycles but bellman only returns the existence of such a cycle and using the parent[] I can navigate up to at least detect one cycle, but not 'all' of them.

Next I'm trying to just do a DFS from the start node and capture any paths that have an edge back to the origin and are less than N length. But that doesn't seem to quite be working.

Is there a standard algorithm for this? Appreciate any pointers. thank you!

UPDATE: I can get what seesm to be a correct answer with DFS if I tweak the DFS logic a bit. if I set this to false to unmark the node as visited it seems to produce all cycles for me, if not (standard DFS) I don't get loops like A=>B=>C=>A and A=>C=>A. Is this still a correct DFS? Is this the right way to get all loops from a given start node?

```
// Recursive depth first search graph traveller
protected dfsWorker(curNode: string, dfsState : DFSState) {
    if (dfsState.finished) {
        return;
    }
    if (!dfsState.traveller.onDfsProcessNodeEarly(curNode, dfsState)) {
        return;
    }
    dfsState.visited.set(curNode, true);
    dfsState.time = dfsState.time + 1 
    dfsState.entryTimes.set(curNode, dfsState.time);

    // Visit all neighbours
    let neighbors = this.graph.get(curNode);
    if (neighbors) {
        for (let [neighbor, graph_edge_node] of neighbors) {

            if (!dfsState.visited.get(neighbor)) {
                // Newly visited node

                dfsState.parent.set(neighbor, curNode);

                dfsState.traveller.onDfsProcessEdgePreRecurse(curNode, neighbor, true, dfsState);

                // Recurse
                this.dfsWorker(neighbor, dfsState);

                dfsState.traveller.onDfsProcessEdgePostRecurse(curNode, neighbor, true, dfsState);
            }
            else
            {
                dfsState.traveller.onDfsProcessEdgePreRecurse(curNode, neighbor, false, dfsState);
            }

            if (dfsState.finished) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    dfsState.traveller.onDfsProcessNodeLate(curNode, dfsState);
    dfsState.time = dfsState.time + 1;
    dfsState.exitTimes.set(curNode, dfsState.time);
    dfsState.processed.set(curNode, true);

    // hack test -- 

    dfsState.visited.set(curNode, false);
}
```

Comment: `Next I'm trying to just do a DFS from the start node and capture any paths that have an edge back to the origin and are less than N length. But that doesn't seem to quite be working.` -- what about it isn't working? If you're trying to track all such cycles, depth first search will find all answers, so you may want to post your code and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It seems to find A=>B=>C=>A, but not A=>C=>A which is also a valid cycle I would like to return as A=>C has a link.  

I actually care about all these cycles... Is that an artifact of doing this with DFS or possibly a bug in my implementation?

Comment: That seems like a bug. DFS is not necessarily the fastest algorithm to solve this problem, but it is a correct algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Well I get a result that seems to be closer what I want if I tweak the DFS logic to unmark a node as visited at the tail of the call. Is that still a valid DFS though? In searches online I've seen some variants of the algo that don't do this unmark and a few that don -- see the //hack test below in the ammended question: